# How to sync time between two different machine

Tags: javascript, java

I have a chat application. I have two machine A & B.
A send a message at 7:10 PM (its own time)
B receive A message at 7:12 PM (its own time)
In server I am storing time (server's own time not any client time) as `Long` JAVA data type.

Problem is when i am getting chat log directly from server its order is correct as all message have server's own time.

But in case A send message directly to B ordering is not proper cos of time mismatch.

Client side is JS & server side is JAVA

Here is what it is like:

```
A (7:10 PM) -----toServer ----> Server (Store message at 7:11PM)
|
+------- directly to B --> B receives message (Its own time is 7:08 PM)
```

Now if i order message at B it will not be in proper order as you can see. Next time when i will fetch from server it will show 7:11PM and time diff between B & Server time will be 3 min.

Answer (score 0):

Just send the server time to the client if it logs in. Then calculate the difference between the client time and use that as offset in the logs.

You could also send the server time each message,  but I don't think that is necessary for a chat application

So if A wants to start chatting, he will sign in to the server and gets a response that also contains the server time. Say A is at 9.30am and the  server  is at 9.33am. The server responds with 9.30am and A knows it's 3 minutes ahead. Then it can correct it's logs time.

Same holds for  B. If A sends a message to B it can sends the server time as well, because it is 3 minutes later that A time.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I have also updated my question have a look